# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) in weblogic

Tags: javascript, java, weblogic12c

I wanted to use common ppp.js file for my weblogic project. I am using this ppp.js in login page and logout page. I'm getting following error in login.jsp page.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I won't get this error in logout.jsp page. I think that this error is occurred because weblogic server doesn't allow to access that .js file, before login to system. it there any way that i can use this file.

(I want to avoid code duplication).

Comment: You should place your code here. Also you should tell more about technologies. Are you using Spring? or Just Servlet/JSP ?

Comment: I am using spring. There is nothing to put as a code. because simply it's not loading the .js file. the issue with the weblogic server. That doesn't allow to use any resources without login to system

Answer (score 0):

In spring configuration file Replace

```
**<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>**
```

With

```
**<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>**
```

And provide the below path in the JSP to load static contents

**`<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/Mass.css" type="text/css"/>`**